# C++ Parent Class with Abstracted Function that Uses Functions in a Child Class

Tags: class, c++11, inheritance

I am trying to create a C++ parent class that has two functions, `f1` and `f2`, to be implemented in the child class. This parent class has a function, `abstractedFunction` that abstracts how `f1` and `f2` should be used together. Both `f1` and `f2` are implemented in the child class as shown in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent
{
public:
    int f1();        // To be implemented in the derived class
    void f2(int i);  // To be implemented in the derived class
    void abstractedFunction() { // Abstracted in the parant class 
        auto r = f1();
        f2(r);
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    int f1() {
        std::cout << "f1 is implemented in the child class\n";
        return 1;
    }

    void f2(int i) {
        std::cout << "f2 is implemented in the child class\n";
        std::cout << "Return value for f1 = " << i << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Child ch;
    ch.abstractedFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Is such a concept implementable in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do something like this. You need to make the functions defined in base class as [pure virtual : Follow this link to know more about them](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/)  and then you can create an object of derived class and assign it to the base pointer to make a required function call

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual int f1()=0;        // To be implemented in the derived class
    virtual void f2(int i)=0;  // To be implemented in the derived class
    void abstractedFunction() { // Abstracted in the parant class 
        auto r = f1();
        f2(r);
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    int f1() {
        std::cout << "f1 is implemented in the child class\n";
        return 1;
    }

    void f2(int i) {
        std::cout << "f2 is implemented in the child class\n";
        std::cout << "Return value for f1 = " << i << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Parent *ptr;
    Child c;
    ptr=&c;
    ptr->abstractedFunction();
    return 0;
}
```